# After add product to cart page goes to top issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, product-list, refresh-statistics

I have the following issue:

I am on the list page, and i have few products. Let's say 100.
If i am going to the 60'th product and i added to the cart, when i press the button to add my product, the product it's added to cart and the page is refreshed.

My issue: when the page is refreshed my page goes to the top everytime, not at the 60'th product when i was before and now i need to scroll down again.

Does anyone know if is any solution, to remain at the same point on the page after refreshing?

Thank you and advance.

Answer (score 1):

It takes to the top of the page because that's where success / failure notifications are displayed.

To stay at the same point you should be looking at an Ajax add to cart solution so either use an online tutorial e.g. http://bit.ly/2uSVjjd
or a 3rd party module.